# Counting if data exists in a row

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Hey guys I have the below sample data which i want to query for.

```
MemberID            AGEQ1       AGEQ2       AGEQ2 
-----------------------------------------------------------------
1217                2           null        null        
58458               3           2           null            
58459               null        null        null            
58457               null        5           null            
299576              6           5           7
```

What i need to do is to lookup the table and if any AGEx COLUMN contains any data then it counts the number of times there is data for that row in each column

Results example:

for memberID 1217 the count would be 1

for memberID 58458 the count would be 2

for memberID 58459 the count would be 0 or null

for memberID 58457 the count would be 1

for memberID 299576 the count would be 3

This is how it should look like in SQL if i query the entire table

1 Children - 2

2 Children - 1

3 Children - 1

0 Children - 1

So far i have been doing it using the following query which isnt very efficient and does give incorrect tallies as there are multiple combinations that people can answer the AGE question. Also i have to write multiple queries and change the is null to is not null depending on how many children i am looking to count a person has

```
select COUNT (*) as '1 Children' from Member
where AGEQ1 is not null
and AGEQ2 is null
and AGEQ3 is null
```

The above query only gives me an answer of 1 but i want to be able to count the other columns for data as well

Hope this is nice and clear and thank you in advance

Comment: How many `AGEx` columns do you have? Is it fixed? And how can this be both mysql and sql server?

Comment: sorry have changed
I have 6 but i have only shown 3 as an example but its the same principle, i dont want to make multiple queries for each combination

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all of the columns are integers, you can take advantage of integer math - dividing the column by itself will yield 1, unless the value is NULL, in which case COALESCE can convert the resulting NULL to 0.

```
SELECT 
    MemberID,
    COALESCE(AGEQ1 / AGEQ1, 0)
  + COALESCE(AGEQ2 / AGEQ2, 0)
  + COALESCE(AGEQ3 / AGEQ3, 0)
  + COALESCE(AGEQ4 / AGEQ4, 0)
  + COALESCE(AGEQ5 / AGEQ5, 0)
  + COALESCE(AGEQ6 / AGEQ6, 0)
FROM dbo.table_name;
```

To get the number of people with each count of children, then:

```
;WITH y(y) AS 
(
  SELECT TOP (7) rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
    (ORDER BY [object_id]) - 1 FROM sys.objects
),
x AS
( 
  SELECT 
     MemberID,
     x = COALESCE(AGEQ1 / AGEQ1, 0)
       + COALESCE(AGEQ2 / AGEQ2, 0)
       + COALESCE(AGEQ3 / AGEQ3, 0)
       + COALESCE(AGEQ4 / AGEQ4, 0)
       + COALESCE(AGEQ5 / AGEQ5, 0)
       + COALESCE(AGEQ6 / AGEQ6, 0)
  FROM dbo.table_name
)
SELECT 
  NumberOfChildren = y.y, 
  NumberOfPeopleWithThatMany = COUNT(x.x) 
FROM y LEFT OUTER JOIN x ON y.y = x.x
GROUP BY y.y ORDER BY y.y;
```

Comment: Oh god that's tricky... I'd stick with the case statement in the other answer if you want future developers to understand what's going on :)

Comment: Great this also gets me similar results to the other answer but how would i get a TOTAL of People who have 1 child or 2 children etc?

Comment: Oh wow you totally hit the nail on the head with that one, even tho i dont completely understand the last answer :)

thank you so much!
Accepted!!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select id, a+b+c+d+e+f 
  from ( select id,
                case when age1 is null then 0 else 1 end a,
                case when age2 is null then 0 else 1 end b,
                case when age3 is null then 0 else 1 end c,
                case when age4 is null then 0 else 1 end d,
                case when age5 is null then 0 else 1 end e,
                case when age6 is null then 0 else 1 end f
          from ages 
       ) as t
```

See here in fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/88020/1

To get the quantity of persons with childs

```
select childs, count(*) as ct
  from (
         select id, a+b+c+d+e+f childs
           from
               (
                select
                      id,
                      case when age1 is null then 0 else 1 end a,
                      case when age2 is null then 0 else 1 end b,
                      case when age3 is null then 0 else 1 end c,
                      case when age4 is null then 0 else 1 end d,
                      case when age5 is null then 0 else 1 end e,
                      case when age6 is null then 0 else 1 end f
                  from ages ) as t
               ) ct
   group by childs
   order by 1
```

See it here at fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/88020/24

Comment: this looks like it could work, but how would i be able to get a total count.

eg TOTAL number of people who have 1 child, 2 children etc

Comment: Edited my answer with what you asked.

Comment: Your answer was alot more understandable and also works and is alot simpler, but im sorry i already accepted the above answer which is also correct

Comment: @InvokeIT There is no problem, glad I could help. It is good enough for me. :)

Answer (score 1):

I'd look at using [UNPIVOT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28SQL.105%29.aspx). That will make your wide column into rows. Since you don't care about what value was in a column, just the presence/absence of value, this will generate a row per not-null column.

The trick then becomes mashing that into the desired output format. It could probably have been done cleaner but I'm a fan of "showing my work" so that others can conform it to their needs.

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/536e1/3)

```
-- Using the above logic
WITH HadAges AS
(
    -- Find everyone and determine number of rows
    SELECT
        UP.MemberID
    ,   count(1) AS rc
    FROM 
        dbo.Member AS M
        UNPIVOT
        (
        ColumnValue for ColumnName in (AGEQ1, AGEQ2, AGEQ3)
        ) AS UP
    GROUP BY
        UP.MemberID
)
, NoAge AS
(
    -- Account for those that didn't show up
    SELECT M.MemberID
    FROM
        dbo.Member AS M
    EXCEPT
    SELECT
        H.MemberID
    FROM
        HadAges AS H
)
, NUMBERS AS
(
    -- Allowable range is 1-6
    SELECT TOP 6
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))  AS TheCount
    FROM
        sys.all_columns AS SC
)
, COMBINATION AS
(
    -- Link those with rows to their count
    SELECT
        N.TheCount AS ChildCount
    ,   H.MemberID
    FROM
        NUMBERS AS N
        LEFT OUTER JOIN
            HadAges AS H
            ON H.rc = N.TheCount
    UNION ALL
    -- Deal with the unlinked
    SELECT
        0
    ,   NA.MemberID
    FROM
        NoAge AS NA
)
SELECT
    C.ChildCount
,   COUNT(C.MemberID) AS Instances
FROM
    COMBINATION AS C
GROUP BY
    C.ChildCount;
```